# Objective-C – iOS5 font rendering has changed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, fonts, ios5

In **iOS4 (4.3 simulator)** when I use the font Myriad Pro with the following font method for a cell:

`cell.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Myriad Pro" size:14];`

It looks like this:

[image]

In **iOS5 (5.0 simulator)** when I use the font Myriad Pro with the same font method it looks like this:

[image]

Has anyone experienced this behaviour as well (perhaps with other fonts?).

Comment: Does it look that way on the device as well, or just the simulator? [bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com/) possibly.

Comment: Looks that way on the device (running iOS5) as well.

Comment: Have you declared the font file correctly in your Info.plist? Myriad Pro is not a standard font on iOS. Also, are you sure that you have a license for Myriad Pro that permits embedding it in your app?

Comment: Did the size of the label change?  Try doing `cell.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO`

Comment: @omz Yes, as you can see it's properly displaying it iOS 4.3 but somehow it's displayed as condensed in iOS 5.0. So that's why I'm wondering if the font rendering has changed in iOS 5.0. Regardless, something is indeed different between the rendering in iOS4 and iOS5. I've set the `Fonts provided by application` key in the App-info.plist to values like "MyriadPro-Regular.otf" and "MyriadPro-Bold.otf". Yes I am sure I have the license but thanks for alerting me.

Comment: @chown Tried that to no avail.

Comment: @SAKrisT I find that a painful framework. I love Objective-C much more than plain C.

Comment: What happens if you pass in "MyriadPro-Regular" instead of "Myriad Pro"?

Comment: @MarkAdams Yes, thanks it was solved by using @"MyriadPro-Regular". I noticed this after some trial and error by myself. Add this as an answer and I'll give you your points ;)

Comment: I am having the same issue with Avenir font, but it works perfect in iOS5 but looks horrible in iOS4.x  Not sure what to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `+fontWithName:size:` on iOS 5, the font name parameter needs to be the full name of the font file in your app bundle and not just the font family name.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I'm using this [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:18.0]

Answer (score 4):

The font rendering has changed in iOS 5. In iOS 4, only one face in a font file was usable no matter how many faces were in the font file and which face you requested.

iOS 5 allows all faces in an embedded font file to be usable.

In our case, we were requesting the regular font but getting the light font instead. In iOS 5 we get back the regular one, which screwed up some UILabel spacing.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if I could see a bigger screenshot, but seems this is [Myriad Pro Condensed](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1707), instead of [Myriad Pro](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1706). [The documentation for `fontWithName:size:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/fontWithName%3asize%3a) says this about `fontName`:

> The fully specified name of the font. This name incorporates both the font family name and the specific style information for the font.

With passing "Myriad Pro" you are only specifying the family name. Maybe system is selecting randomly a wrong member of the font family for you. So try saying the full name of the typeface you want, which is "Myriad Pro Regular" in this case.