# iOS 5 Custom Fonts

Tags: ios, uifont

I have added custom fonts to my resources and bundle resources and also to my plist.  Everything works fine in iOS5 but when I try the iOS 4.3 simulator, none of the custom fonts work.

Any idea why?

Here is a sample of how I am accessing the fonts:

```
lblWait.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNextLTPro-Medium" size:22];
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact list of values you have in your plist under `Fonts provided by application`?

Answer (score 24):

The names in that NSString in the first parameter have to be spot on and what's weird is that it's not consistent.  It depends on if it's a .otf file or a .ttf file.  I've found that a .otf file uses the postscript name and .ttf uses the full name. A good way to find these is to open the font file in Font Book and find it's information (cmd-I).  I would try either to see what sticks.

[image]

**Edit:**

It's not always that the TTF uses the FULLNAME and the OTF uses the POSTSCRIPT name, you should try both.

Comment: This is good feedback. I was able to get this particular font to work on the iOS 5.1 Simulator, iOS 4.3 Simulator, and an iPhone running iOS 4.1. The OTF file was named `AvenirNextLTPro-Medium.otf` and had an internal PostScript name of `AvenirNextLTPro-Medium`.

Comment: warrenm, yes that will work, but the font looks way different when you switch between ios4.3 and ios5.  I am still having issues here.  Nothing is consistent.  When I use the Full Name, setting any of the font sizes does nothing!  When I use the postscript name, font sizes work, font works in ios5, but font does not work in anything under ios5 which was my original issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980812/objective-c-ios5-font-rendering-has-changed

Comment: warrenm, try to use multiple avenir fonts...you wont be able to....The font rendering has changed in iOS 5. In iOS 4, only one face in a font file was usable no matter how many faces were in the font file and which face you requested.

iOS 5 allows all faces in an embedded font file to be usable.

In our case, we were requesting the regular font but getting the light font instead. In iOS 5 we get back the regular one, which screwed up some UILabel spacing.

Comment: This answer points an important problem, but it's not always that the OTF uses  the POSTSCRIPT or the TTF uses the FULLNAME, I just had to use the postscript name with a ttf file.

Comment: I was able to use a .ttf font with the PostScript name (HandOfSean) instead the Full name (Hand Of Sean).

Answer (score 9):

Many times the source of this problem is that the font file is added to the project **but not to the target**.

Click on the font and make sure it's ticked in "Target Membership", in the right hand column.